# Which API url to get all categories list in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

Need API url to get all categories in magento 1.9

Comment: check this out: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalogCategory.html

Answer (score 0):

As @BareFeet mentioned you can look into documentation link.
You'll be probably more interested in the method `catalogCategoryTree`:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html

My configuration would point to this url: https://myhost/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1

Just check the link from documentation or use the one provided.